# Nested IF statement to ignore blanks

Tags: excel

can anyone please help me in writing nested if statement and ignoring blanks.

Below is the formulae that i am trying.

```
=IF(A1=" "," ",IF(A1=B2,"Conflict",IF(B1=A2,"Conflict"," ")))
```

So problem with above formulae is even cells A1 and B2 are blanks still it is evaluating to bring Conflict, but i want to see Blank.

Same if B1 and A2 are blanks it should bring blank.

Please help.

Regards,
Raj.

Comment: Blank check will be "" instead of " "

Comment: It's exactly as @RanjitSingh said: replace your `" "` with `""`

Comment: Perfect, simple thing i messed it up. It worked guys. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Guy's, i got on more issue. the formulae working fine if all four cells are blanks, but if there is a value in A1 and blank in B2, it is showing Conflict and that's not right, i want to see blank. Probably i am missing something.

Comment: Please, do not ask again in comments never ever. If you have a new different question, open a new one.

Comment: @Raj - In what scenario you want to show conflict and in what scenario you want to show empty. Include some example in question